# Twirl templates cannot be seen in the code (spray application)

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, twirl

I have some configuration problem I can't see. I've followed the instructions provided in the latest [`twirl`](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) README, but the `html` package is undefined according to the compiler.

1. I've included the `sbt-twirl` plugin in the `project/plugins.sbt` file

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.0.3")
   ```
2. In the `project/Build.scala` I've enabled the plugin

   ```
    lazy val root  = Project(id = "proj", base = file("."))
      .enablePlugins(play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl)
      .settings(rootSettings: _*)
   ```
3. I've placed the `page.scala.html` in the `src/main/twirl` subdirectory (either directly or using the `com/somethin/cool` path)

Now if I'm trying to import the `html` package (or `com.somethin.cool.html`) the compiler complains it's undefined. I can compile the templates with 'twirlCompile' command, and they get properly generated in the `target` subdirectory, but they are invisible to the main project.

#### Note: This is *not* a PlayFramework project

- Scala: 2.10.4
- sbt: 0.13.6
- twirl: 1.0.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I similarly use Twirl in a non-Play project.

If you placed the file in `src/main/com/somethin/cool` then you should expect the generated class to be found at `com.somethin.cool.html.page`

If you placed the file in `src/main/twirl/` then you should expect the generated class to be found at `twirl.html.page`

The Twirl compiler looks at the files it finds and puts the "html" (extension really, it could be "txt" or "json" or ...) directory underneath the longest common sub-path of the files. So, say you had:

```
src/main/com/somethin/cool/page1.scala.html
src/main/twirl/page2.scala.html
```

Then the common longest sub-path of the files is src/main (i.e. the root of the classpath). You're then going to get these classes at:

```
html.com.somethin/cool/page1
html.twirl.page2
```

Now, to address the "compiler complains it's undefined" part: you could mean several things by this.

If you mean the actual Scala Compiler being run by sbt doesn't find it, I've never had a problem with that. The generated source and .class files are in the path under `target/scala_2.10/twirl/main`. In that case, you might want to be more clear about the compiler's complaint and your compilation classpath.

But, if you mean that your IDE doesn't recognize the source file, you'll need to add the directory `target/scala_2.10/twirl/main` as one of the source directories used by your project.

One other issue I have with Twirl usage is that the IntelliJ IDEA 14 IDE doesn't really support the twirl compiler, at least not outside a Play project. Whenever I update a Twirl template, I invariably have to compile it with sbt instead of IntelliJ IDEA's built-in compiler. The JetBrains people tell me they are working on a fix for this (I've logged an issue with them about it.)

UPDATE(12/14/14): The JetBrains issue I logged is [at this location](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7861). The test case for it is [here on github](https://github.com/reid-spencer/im-going-twirly)

Answer (score 3):

it might help to explicitly add an unmanaged source directory in sbt.

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "target" / "yourTwirlGeneratedSources"
```

However, this should certainly not be necessary! I suppose when running `compile` the dependency on `twirlCompile` won't be resolved either and no updated sources are generated from your twirl files?

Have you tried using previous combinations of twirl + sbt?